# How to display the tooltip of an unclickable marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've noticed on a client map that hovering over unclickable markers (with titles) no longer shows a tooltip. 
It seems as if Google changed this!

Here is a [2009 GMapsV3 tutorial showing a tooltip for an unclickable marker](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/07/google-maps-api-3-markers/). The tooltip doesn't show (anymore)!

This [tutorial shows a tooltip for a clickable marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "clickable: false" option makes the difference. With clickable disabled you don't get a cursor-pointer and no title. The tutorial from 2009 loads always the latest version of the api. Google does change a lot of things in every minor version.

Here is the changelog but i does not find an exact match where this change was documented:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog

Comment: But both me Svennerberg (the tutorial author) found it more usable if a marker with no info window to open is made unclickable, while still preserving the tooltip on hover.

Comment: But i see the problem that the user don't recognized that there is any information behind a icon where you get no cursor change feedback. With the click able icon the cursor changed from a grap-hand to a pointer. It tells the user - "hey wait i have some information for you" and i think that is good usability.